# Is there any way I can get context from fragmentmanager?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have an extension function with `FragmentManager` as receiver. I have used it at **atleast 75 places**. Now I want to access `sharedpreference` in that extension. All I need is context inside that function. Any way I can access context?

Here is how function looks,

```
inline fun FragmentManager?.loadFragment(...){
 ....
 // Loading of fragment
 // inside I want context
}
```

Comment: Overload method `loadFragment` with context as parameter ..

Comment: I thought so and I did with optional params but I simply cannot because it is used in several places which is why I asked.

Comment: You can not get Context from a `FragmentManager` so i think this is what you should do .. There could be cases where you do not need Context So you can utilize both variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer is returning null `context` as it is not advisable to use by @Thomas. So I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/6330489).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get context from `FragmentManager`, but I would not advise it.

```
 inline fun FragmentManager?.loadFragment() {
    // Get the context of the last fragment added to the fragment manager
    val context = this?.fragments?.last()?.context

 }
```

Comment: Thats exactly how I did it, the only difference is I used `findFragmentById`, my need of context was after the second fragment. So this solved my problem. Thanks for your help